# Soundcloud API - Why are stream_urls for a particular artist not working anymore (404)

Tags: soundcloud

my site streams Soundcloud tracks from various bands using SoundManager2 with the Soundcloud stream_url and added secret_token and client_id. All bands seem to be working except one, and I can't see anything in the API responses that show any difference.

Here is the specific set that has been working for weeks, but started returning a 404 today:
https://soundcloud.com/mona-official/sets/torches-pitchforks

The band says they haven't changed anything with their settings, Apps and Widgets are enabled, AND streamable is true for all the tracks in the API - the songs seems to be public anyway and play fine on soundcloud.com.  The band's access token still seems to be valid as well.

Thanks!
Rick

Comment: I am also seeing an issue like this, however our stream URLs are resolving 200s, but blank.

Comment: The same happens to me too. I even checked it with their console because I feared that some of my code could be wrong or something. I find it strange btw. that stackoverflow is their way to answer dev-questions but if someone asks a question, they almost never get an answer, like this one for example. As of today it was asked 30 days ago ...

Answer (score 4):

Here is one ugly workaround if your app can check 404 on stream:

Calling

`https://api.soundcloud.com/i1/tracks/<track_id>/streams?client_id=<cid>`

will respond in unconditional JSON response (that is you can't get XML) with RTMP stream, that will be valid for couple of minutes or so:

`{"rtmp_mp3_128_url":"rtmp://ec-rtmp-media.soundcloud.com:80/mp3:VeAGXsGTFb59.128?9527d18f1063a01f059bf10590159adb10dea0996b8c0cdb6748962c2c1b859ce6b56ee301b0b087e0695d03f6e9498fd963ef1328bc89c05e156bacca00317de55e78139e168138ead65c8fdac11f8d626674293d53f230cf5a"}`