# Getting stream url raises 404

Tags: python, soundcloud

Getting a track for a permanent track url (copied from website):

```
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id = xxx)
track = client.get('/resolve', url = 'http://soundcloud.com/igapromotion/u2-the-miracle-of-joey-ramone')
```

The returned track has 'sharing' set to 'public' and 'streamable' yields True.

Resolve the stream url:

```
stream_url = client.get(track.stream_url, allow_redirects=False)
```

This delivers an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/soundcloud/client.py", line 130, in _request
    return wrapped_resource(make_request(method, url, kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/soundcloud/request.py", line 134, in make_request
    result.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 795, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found
```

This is for most tracks, but not all.

Comment: Your URL is wrong - that's what the 404 indicates.  I'd triple check that you're hitting the right location by referencing Soundcloud's API.

Comment: Yes, one could think this ;) But the url is passed to "client.get", and the result is correct (artist, comment, etc.). What fails is getting the stream url..

Answer (score 0):

I posted a bug for this. A workaround is described here: [Soundcloud API - Why are stream_urls for a particular artist not working anymore (404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852634/soundcloud-api-why-are-stream-urls-for-a-particular-artist-not-working-anymore)

In python code:

```
stream_url = client.get('/i1/tracks/' + str(track.id) + '/streams?client_id=' + client_id).rtmp_mp3_128_url
```